# query without subqueries? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to do this query without any subqueries? Or any less code? To get the same result.

```
SELECT person 
FROM tbla 
WHERE person IN 
(SELECT person 
FROM tblb 
WHERE age IN 
(SELECT age 
FROM tblc 
where age = '20'));
```

Comment: Not really possible to answer this without knowing the structure of the tables you are selecting from.

Comment: Thank you all for quick response. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tbla.person 
FROM tbla 
inner join tblb on tblb.person = tbla.person
inner join tblc on tblc.age = tblb.age
WHERE tblc.age = '20'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use join but a `DISTINCT` keyword is required to eliminate duplicate rows.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    tbla a
        INNER JOIN tblb b
            ON a.person = b.person
        INNER JOIN tblc c
            ON b.age = c.age
WHERE   c.age = 20
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `tblc` and `tblb` as an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT tbla.person 
FROM tbla 
INNER JOIN tblb 
  ON tblb.person = tbla.person 
INNER JOIN tblc 
  ON tblc.age = tblb.age 
WHERE tblc.age = 20;
```